# using pdfkit to display pdf

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I'm trying to load a `pdf` that is stored in my app, here is the code that I have

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example", withExtension: "pdf")
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
        self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
    }
```

> When I am running in simulator, I am getting the error that **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** in the debug are it is showing that *url is nil* .Any idea how to resolve it? I am running swift 4 and iOS 11 as target

Comment: Check that "example.pdf" is actually copied in your project, accessible and has the right name and extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please click the checkbox under Target Membership in File Inspector.

[image: File Inspector - Target Membership]

Comment: Yes this was the problem, under target membership, one will see the App name and has to check that for working